# sum of array values from phpmysql

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, function

```
<?php
$query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM vph");
while($array=mysql_fetch_array($query)){

    echo $a= $array['vph_weight'];// $a is like this 1,2,3,2,5,,,,,..
}
?>
```

I want to add `$a` values. Please help to add those value. I am new in PHP.

Comment: Delcare `$a` variable outside while `$a=0`; inside while add `$a=$a+$array['vph_weight']`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simply rewrite your query as below instead of doing a separate `array_sum()` operation **overhead** !

```
SELECT SUM(vph_weight) AS vphsum FROM vph
```

###The code..

```
$query=mysql_query("SELECT SUM(vph_weight) AS vphsum FROM vph");
while($array=mysql_fetch_array($query)){

    echo $array['vphsum'];
}
```

---

This (`mysql_*`) extension is deprecated as of `PHP 5.5.0`, and will be removed in the future. Instead, **Prepared Statements** of [`MySQLi`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) or [`PDO_MySQL`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) extension should be used to ward off SQL Injection attacks !

Comment: +1 This is a much more efficient approach than that in the "selected" answer. The only reason to use the pattern in the "selected" answer is as a demonstration of the performance difference between that, and the better pattern in this answer.

Answer (score -1):

> $query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM vph");
>
> ```
>      $sum = 0;
>      while($array=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
>          $sum += $array['vph_weight'];
>      }  
>      echo "VPH Weight Sum: ".$sum;
> ```

**Edit**: I would recommend using shankar's solution, if you need to deal only with the `vph_weight` value of table. But if you doing something else (except summing vph field) with the data getting from query. You can consider this solution.